# XTEA Block Cipher

Tags: c#, security, cryptography

Usually people recommend to never implement cryptographic algorithms yourself unless you are an expert in the field. This of course makes a lot of sense mainly because there are numerous things that can go wrong, resulting in a vulnerable implementation.

However, for learning purposes I decided to write an implementation of the [XTEA block cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XTEA) myself nonetheless. XTEA is a 64-bit block feistel cipher with a 128-bit key.

What can be improved in my implementation? Are there any major flaws?

**ISymmetricEncryptionProvider.cs**

```
namespace Crypto
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides a base for symmetric encryption algorithms
    /// </summary>
    public interface ISymmetricEncryptionProvider
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Symmetric encryption routine
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="data">The data that should get encrypted</param>
        /// <returns>The encrypted data</returns>
        byte[] Encrypt(byte[] data);


        /// <summary>
        /// Symmetric decryption routine 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="data">The data that should get decrypted</param>
        /// <returns>The decrypted data</returns>
        byte[] Decrypt(byte[] data);

    }
}
```

**XTEA.cs**

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Crypto
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Like TEA, XTEA is a 64-bit block Feistel cipher with a 128-bit key and a suggested
    /// 64 rounds. Several differences from TEA are apparent, including a somewhat
    /// more complex key-schedule and a rearrangement of the shifts, XORs, and additions.
    /// 
    /// More information can be found here:
    /// + https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XTEA
    /// + http://www.tayloredge.com/reference/Mathematics/TEA-XTEA.pdf
    /// </summary>
    public class XTEA : ISymmetricEncryptionProvider
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The 128 bit key used for encryption and decryption
        /// </summary>
        private readonly uint[] _key;


        /// <summary>
        /// The number of rounds, default is 32 because each iteration performs two Feistel-cipher rounds.
        /// </summary>
        private readonly uint _cycles;


        /// <summary>
        /// XTEA operates with a block size of 8 bytes
        /// </summary>
        private readonly uint _blockSize = 8;


        /// <summary>
        /// The delta is derived from the golden ratio where delta = (sqrt(2) - 1) * 2^31
        /// A different multiple of delta is used in each round so that no bit of
        /// the multiple will not change frequently
        /// </summary>
        private const uint Delta = 0x9E3779B9;


        /// <summary>
        /// Instantiate new XTEA object for encryption/decryption
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="key">The encryption/decryption key</param>
        /// <param name="cycles">Number of cycles performed, default is 32</param>
        public XTEA(byte[] key, uint cycles = 32)
        {
            _key = GenerateKey(key);
            _cycles = cycles;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Calculates the next multiple of the block size of the input data because
        /// XTEA is a 64-bit cipher.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="length">Input data size</param>
        /// <returns>Input data extended to the next multiple of the block size.</returns>
        private uint NextMultipleOfBlockSize(uint length)
        {
            return (length + 7) / _blockSize * _blockSize;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Encrypts the provided data with XTEA
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="data">The data to encrypt</param>
        /// <returns>Encrypted data as byte array</returns>
        public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] data)
        {
            var blockBuffer = new uint[2];
            var dataBuffer = new byte[NextMultipleOfBlockSize((uint)data.Length + 4)];
            var lengthBuffer = BitConverter.GetBytes(data.Length);

            Buffer.BlockCopy(lengthBuffer, 0, dataBuffer, 0, lengthBuffer.Length);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(data, 0, dataBuffer, lengthBuffer.Length, data.Length);

            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(dataBuffer))
            using (var binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(memoryStream))
                for (uint i = 0; i < dataBuffer.Length; i += _blockSize)
                {
                    blockBuffer[0] = BitConverter.ToUInt32(dataBuffer, (int) i);
                    blockBuffer[1] = BitConverter.ToUInt32(dataBuffer, (int) i + 4);

                    Encode(_cycles, blockBuffer, _key);

                    binaryWriter.Write(blockBuffer[0]);
                    binaryWriter.Write(blockBuffer[1]);
                }

            return dataBuffer;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Decrypts the provided data with XTEA
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="data">The data to decrypt</param>
        /// <returns>The decrypted data as byte array</returns>
        public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] data)
        {
            // Encrypted data size must be a multiple of the block size
            if (data.Length % _blockSize != 0)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(data));

            var blockBuffer = new uint[2];
            var buffer = new byte[data.Length];

            Buffer.BlockCopy(data, 0, buffer, 0, data.Length);

            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
            using (var binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(memoryStream))
            {
                for (uint i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i += _blockSize)
                {
                    blockBuffer[0] = BitConverter.ToUInt32(buffer, (int) i);
                    blockBuffer[1] = BitConverter.ToUInt32(buffer, (int) i + 4);

                    Decode(_cycles, blockBuffer, _key);

                    binaryWriter.Write(blockBuffer[0]);
                    binaryWriter.Write(blockBuffer[1]);
                }
            }

            // Verify if length of output data is valid
            var length = BitConverter.ToUInt32(buffer, 0);
            VerifyDataLength(length, buffer.Length, 4);

            // Trim first 4 bytes of output data            
            return TrimOutputData(length, buffer, 4);
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Removes the first n bytes from the buffer
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="length">Length of the output buffer</param>
        /// <param name="buffer">The output buffer</param>
        /// <param name="trimSize">Number of bytes to trim from the start of the buffer</param>
        /// <returns>Trimmed output buffer array</returns>
        private byte[] TrimOutputData(uint length, byte[] buffer, int trimSize)
        {
            var result = new byte[length];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, trimSize, result, 0, (int) length);
            return result;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Compares the length of the output data from a specified offset to the length of the buffer
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dataLength">Length of the output data</param>
        /// <param name="bufferLength">Length of the buffer</param>
        /// <param name="offset">The offset</param>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException">Thrown if buffer data is corrupted</exception>
        private void VerifyDataLength(uint dataLength, int bufferLength, uint offset)
        {
            if (dataLength > bufferLength - offset)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(bufferLength));
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Transforms the key to uint[]
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Transformed key</returns>
        private uint[] GenerateKey(byte[] key)
        {
            if (key.Length != 16)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(key));

            return new[]
            {
                BitConverter.ToUInt32(key, 0), BitConverter.ToUInt32(key, 4),
                BitConverter.ToUInt32(key, 8), BitConverter.ToUInt32(key, 12)
            };
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// TEA inplace encoding routine of the provided data array.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="rounds">The number of encryption rounds, default is 32.</param>
        /// <param name="v">The data array containing two values.</param>
        /// <param name="k">The key array containing 4 values.</param>
        private void Encode(uint rounds, uint[] v, uint[] k)
        {
            uint sum = 0;
            uint v0 = v[0], v1 = v[1];
            for (int i = 0; i < rounds; i++)
            {
                v0 += (((v1 << 4) ^ (v1 >> 5)) + v1) ^ (sum + k[sum & 3]);
                sum += Delta;
                v1 += (((v0 << 4) ^ (v0 >> 5)) + v0) ^ (sum + k[(sum >> 11) & 3]);
            }

            v[0] = v0;
            v[1] = v1;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// TEA inplace decoding routine of the provided data array.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="rounds">The number of encryption rounds, default is 32.</param>
        /// <param name="v">The data array containing two values.</param>
        /// <param name="k">The key array containing 4 values.</param>
        private void Decode(uint rounds, uint[] v, uint[] k)
        {
            uint sum = Delta * rounds;
            uint v0 = v[0], v1 = v[1];
            for (int i = 0; i < rounds; i++)
            {
                v1 -= (((v0 << 4) ^ (v0 >> 5)) + v0) ^ (sum + k[(sum >> 11) & 3]);
                sum -= Delta;
                v0 -= (((v1 << 4) ^ (v1 >> 5)) + v1) ^ (sum + k[sum & 3]);
            }

            v[0] = v0;
            v[1] = v1;
        }

    }
}
```

Here is an example usage of the class:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    byte[] key = {0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 
                  0x08, 0x09, 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x0D, 0x0E, 0x0F};

    byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("This is a message which will be encrypted with XTEA!");

    var xtea = new XTEA(key);
    var enc = xtea.Encrypt(data);
    var dec = xtea.Decrypt(enc);

    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dec));
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**References**

Credit where credit belongs. During the writing of this class used the following websites/books as a guideline:

[The Tiny Encryption Algorithm (TEA)](http://www.tayloredge.com/reference/Mathematics/TEA-XTEA.pdf)

[C# implementation of XTEA](https://gist.github.com/InfectedBytes/ff8d5de8592bfc711380801cb29b3915)

[C# CarestiaXTEA](https://github.com/ercsoftworks/CarestiaXTEA)

[C++ XTEA Implementation](https://github.com/IU5HKU/XTEA)

Comment: I would add a method to fold/spindle/mutilate and generally munge up the key before deleting it.  You might also automatically call that method when closing the class (if C# allows).  Your deletion will not be fully secure unless you delve into the OS, but it is a useful thing to think about when coding cryptographic primitives.

Comment: Also your documentation should probably actually say that the encrypt / decrypt functions use the insecure ECB mode.

Comment: @rossum Very good catch. Yes, that is possible with C#. However, I am not sure what you mean by _fold/spindle/mutilate and generally munge up the key_. Shouldn't deleting the key from memory be good enough when the class is destroyed?

Comment: @SEJPM Very valid point. Now that you mention it, I should definitely  chose CBC mode instead of ECB. From my understanding this is pretty simple. XOR'ing the previous block with the current block should be fine?

Comment: @766F6964 yes, for encryption you run the XOR of your last ciphertext and current plaintext through the block cipher.

Comment: Regarding key deletion, you also need to take into account that the GC can move objects around, so unless you pin something there could be multiple copies of its data lying around by the time you're done.

Comment: I mean overwite the key in memory with something else, perhaps many times, like the various secure delete programs for discs, before you delete it from memory.  @Peter is right about possible other copies lying around, but finding and deleting those (or stopping them happening) is for an advanced class.  For the moment the point is that keys need to be securely overwritten and deleted if possible.

Comment: Another thing: what's the reason for that length prefix? Why not use a padding scheme like PKCS#7 instead?

Comment: @PieterWitvoet Good point. Even tho the .NET framework supports [PKCS7](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.paddingmode?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Security_Cryptography_PaddingMode_PKCS7) I can't seem to find a way to manually pad a message to a certain block size when I am not explicitly using the [SymmetricAlgorithm](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm?view=netframework-4.7.2) class.

Comment: @SEJPM Are there any resources for a good CBC XTEA implementation that might be worth looking into?

Comment: CBC is a fairly easy mode, so if your XTEA implementation passes all the usual test vectors and your CBC implementation is correct (can eg be checked by plugging in the identity function or the reverse function as "cipher") then you should be good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you call `Encode` really seems to be your block encryption function, I would name it something more suggestive of that.  As noted in the comments, it would be great it you offered modes other than ECB, it would be a good exercise to design that well.  My main complaint is that it's oriented around byte arrays, when a `Stream`-based implementation would be more useful.  Either:

```
void Encrypt(Stream input, Stream output)
```

or something more like an adapter pattern:

```
class XTeaEncryptor : Stream
{
    XTeaEncryptor(Stream outputStream){}
}
```

It's much easier to use a class designed for `Stream`s to encrypt a byte array than vice versa, especially when you get into other modes.

Your use of `TrimOutputData` results in you allocating an array almost as big as the input, you could avoid this by using an index.